# Use a separate template for the home page only

Tags: templates, get-template-part

I use Pinboard theme (it has a very complicated structure, but it is nice).

[Image how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPYLr.gif)
Select a template in this way it changes for all posts, pages, etc. and do not give you more choice.

I tried experimenting with index file but it is too confusing for me.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if( is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <?php if( pinboard_get_option( 'slider' ) ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'slider' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'wide' ); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar( 'boxes' ); ?>
<?php elseif( ( is_home() && is_paged() ) || ( ! is_home() && pinboard_get_option( 'location' ) ) ) : ?>
    <?php pinboard_current_location(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="container">
    <section id="content" <?php pinboard_content_class(); ?>>
        <?php if( is_category( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ) || ( is_category() && cat_is_ancestor_of( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ), get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
            <?php pinboard_category_filter( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="entries">
                <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div><!-- .entries -->
            <?php pinboard_posts_nav(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php pinboard_404(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section><!-- #content -->
    <?php if( 'no-sidebars' != pinboard_get_option( 'layout' ) && 'full-width' != pinboard_get_option( 'layout' ) && ! is_category( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ) ) && ! ( is_category() && cat_is_ancestor_of( pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ), get_queried_object() ) ) ) : ?>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->
```

I made front-page.php with the code from template-blog-full-width.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php global $pinboard_page_template; ?>
<?php $pinboard_page_template = 'template-blog-full-width.php'; ?>
<?php if( pinboard_get_option( 'location' ) ) : ?>
    <?php pinboard_current_location(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="container">
    <section id="content" class="column onecol">
        <?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), 'paged' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ); ?>
        <?php if( pinboard_get_option( 'blog_exclude_portfolio' ) ) : ?>
            <?php $args['cat'] = '-' . pinboard_get_option( 'portfolio_cat' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php global $wp_query, $wp_the_query; ?>
        <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
        <?php if( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="entries">
                <?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div><!-- .entries -->
            <?php pinboard_posts_nav(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php pinboard_404(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php $wp_query = $wp_the_query; ?>
    </section><!-- #content -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->
```

But it looks bad [my site](http://szuta.pl)

I would like to have a home page template: template-blog-full-width.php
and the rest would be defined by the options.

If anything is unclear, I'll try to explain.

Comment: Did you read [Creating_a_Static_Front_Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `template-blog-full-width.php` is a page template and that you'd like to use this page template as the template to be used on the homepage.

What you can do is to create a copy of the `template-blog-full-width.php` template and name the copy `front-page.php`.

That's about it. WordPress will always use [**`front-page.php`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display) template when on the homepage/frontpage of your website.

**And just a side note**

You might want to implement your changes by creating a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) first so that any updates to the parent theme won't remove your changes..

Comment: That did't work well, the site have bugs. :( But thanx for concern.